# Every diagonalisable matrix has pairwise distinct eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove whether or not every diagonalisable matrix has pairwise distinct eigenvalues.

My instinct is to think that the statement is true as for a matrix to be diagonalisable there has to exist a basis consisting of the eigenvectors of the matrix. However, I am unsure what is meant by 'pairwise distinct'.

Comment: Look at identity matrix. It's diagonalisable and has only  one eigenvalue.

Comment: The matrix $I$ is diagonalisable... but the eigenvalues aren't distinct.

Comment: @sigmabe Oh, obviously!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating the obvious counterexample of *sigmabe* to get this off of the Unanswered queue: the identity matrix clearly is both diagonalizable and has repeated eigenvalues.